# Django 4 Running some python codes/files outside views for specific request and returning the parameters as context before rendering template

Tags: django, django-views

I am relatively new to Django, while I am fine with loading static pages etc, I have an issue with complex dynamic content.

I am designing a quiz, when a user answers a question, I would like to log some parameters into the database (correct or wrong, time taken for the response, etc). When the user clicks next, I want to analyse the data from the answer to the previous question, apply an algorithm and select the question and its parameters as context to the template so that the next question is loaded.

So far, I have created a config.py that lets me take the parameters (context) from quiz.py and use them in views.py. Both config.py and quiz.py are in the main folder of the Quiz App.

The problem I have is how to read and analyse the user session and data in my quiz.py so that I could apply the algorithm based on the user's previous answers and performance on the database.

I have looked at many forums, videos, etc but not even sure if I am on the right path. I have looked at Middleware, Threading, using Celery, etc and I cannot get the user data from "request" in quiz.py.

Much appreciate someone's help.

Comment: Do you already have an algorithm? The algorithm doesn't select the next question based on the previous inputs for you? Do you know what criteria you would use to select the next question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.